# Control goes to next statement immediately after running a command using Run method

Tags: command-line, vbscript, silent

I have script to uninstall a package say pkg_1 using it's uninstallstring (i.e. setup.exe -remove). After that it is trying to remove another package say pkg_2. The uninstallation of pkg_1 takes around 1 to 2 minutes. the script looks like as below

```
rc = shellobj.Run("cmd /C " & uninstall_string_1 & " /silent",0, true)
rc1 = shellobj.Run("cmd /C " & uninstall_string_2 & " /silent",0, true)
```

Here what's my problem is, if you place WScript.sleep(120000) between above two statements, both packages are getting removed successfully. Otherwise, uninstaaltion of pkg_1 is halted and uninstallation of pkg_2 begins immediately. As a result only pkg_2 is getting removed(without sleep).

How can i do the uninstallation of two packages without using sleep method?

FYI 
If you run uninstall_string_1 from command prompt, new prompt will be opned after 0-5 seconds and uninstallation proceeds in background

Answer (score 0):

Arjun, I read this in another forum :

When we use scripts to install or uninstall packages, it depends very much on the implementation of the package. Let's say setup.exe itself run as process A. Process A does some nominal verification then spawns a process B, the real installation engine, then close itself out. In this case, the bWaitOnReturn(which you have set to true in your code) has done its work and the control will hand to the next statement. However, the process B is still running. That is out of the control of the bWaitOnReturn. So your 2nd package will start before your 1rst package is actually completed. Maybe your 1rst package is not actually halted, it might be taking time and executing in the background. Thats just a guess anyways.

If that is not the case, can you also try this :

```
Set obj0 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = obj0.Exec("your package../../")
'  We will set a loop until finished
Do While objExec.Status <> 1
WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

So every 100ms, script will check if your package has completed execution. And if it has, it will move to next statement.

Comment: As you said pkg_1 uninstallation is not getting halted. But sometimes pkg_1 is getting removed and sometimes not. The code you mentioned is not working for me (i.e. not solving this issue)

Comment: @ arjun - Ok.. Maybe someone else can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
strCmd = uninstall_string_1 & " & " & uninstall_string_2
rc = shellObj.Run("cmd /C " & strCmd, 0, True)
```

Comment: This is also not working for me. It is trying to execute both commands at a time.